# composer update drupal/drupal does not work : Nothing to install or update

Tags: 8, updating, composer

I’ve installed several Drupal 8 site with composer as it is strongly recommended.

I can update modules like this :

```
composer require drupal/pathauto:1.1
```

But I can't update core with

`composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies` (as seen in documentation)

or (think should be like this in my case) :

```
composer update drupal/drupal --with-dependencies
```

I try tu update from 8.4.2 to 8.5.0 in this website.

I’ve read a lot of topics on this, I’ve tried :

- remove folder /vendor
- remove composer.lock

But it didn’t work.

How can I update my classic Drupal (nothing fancy in it) with composer ? Should I gave up and update with Drush ?

Her is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "drupal/drupal",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0+",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
        "drupal/contact_block": "^1.4",
        "drupal/twig_tweak": "^1.9",
        "drupal/contact_ajax": "^1.4@beta",
        "drupal/pathauto": "1.1",
        "drupal/easy_breadcrumb": "^1.6",
        "drupal/redirect": "1.1",
        "drupal/views_slideshow": "^4.6",
        "drupal/bootstrap": "3.11",
        "drush/drush": "dev-master"
    },
    "replace": {
        "drupal/core": "^8.4"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
    },
    "extra": {
        "_readme": [
            "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
            "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
            "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
            "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
            "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
        ],
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "core/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": false,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-extra": false
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "post-autoload-dump": [
          "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess"
        ],
        "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Finally, i could update with these modifications.

**Step 1**, optional in case your `composer.json`contains this. If it is ok, apply step 2

add

```
"require": {
        ---
        "drupal/core": "~8.5"
    },
```

remove

```
"replace": {
    "drupal/core": "^8.4"
},
```

**Step 2**

delete this folder :

```
vendor
```

delete this file :

```
composer.lock
```

run

```
composer update --with-dependencies
```

Comment: For me this worked without the option "--with-dependencies". I believe that an unqualified "composer update" does update the dependencies anyway. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update

Comment: For me this worked too. I had to remove composer.lock and vendor folder.  I didnt change the version numbers in my composer.json files though.

Answer (score 0):

In your "require" section, change the version from drupal/core:"8.4" to drupal/core:"8.5" and run 
`composer update`

Comment: Do I have to change this manually each time I want to update or was is an issue with composer.json ?

Comment: Thanks, I’ve tested and like I said in my previous answer, I had also to delete `vendor` and `composer.lock` (`require` is necessary but not enough)